# Help Reading this Data in XML as a List (ContentReader)

Tags: xna, c#, xml

Edit:

So i'm going to rephrase the question a bit, seeing as now i think know how i'm going to read this data. Looking at this example as my guide:
http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/53404/323877.aspx

This is pretty much what i'm currently doing, and to be clear and show you guys:
http://pastebin.com/GxqQcBDg, that's how i'm loading my data.

So looking at that guys example from his post, he has a similar layout, his "Enemies" can equal my element "Animated_Tiles" and then his "Items" could be equal to my "Tile" objects, at least if you compare my data to his they look extremely similar, and yes i did update the Data as Richard Marskell - Drackir suggested, 
But i'm wondering if i can have "Type" definitions like the guy has in his example, to show what i mean:

```
  <Animated_Tiles Type="System.Collections.Generic.List[Namespace.Class]">
```

Can that be done? Or is it only the "Asset" element that can have the Type definition?
Currently this is what my new data layout looks like:
http://pastebin.com/i42166ZQ

But currently, it seems to start reading it but i get this error by the first "Tile" Element. So the only difference i see between his & my layouts are that he has the Asset containing the List definition whereas i have "Animated_Tiles". So i'm unsure can any element can have the "Type=Blah" definition?

Comment: Are you planning on loading it using the content loader, or is it dynamic data loaded at run-time?

Comment: Did you make that file? The reason you're having trouble figuring out how to use it is because it was poorly made. If you convert `<Tile#>` to `<Tile id="#">`, I think you'll find that it's much easier to read. (Since `Animated_Tiles` will essentially become an array of `Tiles` instead of an object with many properties.)

Comment: @MindWorX Yes, i'm planning on loading this through the content-loader. And Richard, I see your point.

Comment: I'd totally upvote that if it was an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i got it going now :). 
It seems that i can have other elements using the "Type=Blah" definition, i didn't know that but it's good to know. 
The Animated_Tiles all needed to be "Items" of the List, i feel stupid :/ make so much sense now that the Elements in the "Animated_Tiles" Element would be required to have the title of Item.

But it works great now :D. Thanks you guys for your answers though.

Answer (score 3):

You could skip Deserializer and just use Linq to Xml:

```
var xelement = XElement.Load(file);
var tiles = xelement.Element("Animated_Tiles")
    .Elements()
    .Where(el => el.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("Tile"))
    .Select(el => new Tile {
        PositionX = (int)el.Element("PositionX"),
        PositionY = (int)el.Element("PositionY"),
        Type = el.Element("Type").Value
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Load in the XML file into a DOM tree and then iterate though the tiles.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317662

Edit: Or use Jimmy's Idea :)